# Which is isomorphic to $2y^2=x^4-17$ ?, $y^2=-34x^4+2$ or $y^2=-34x^4-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I heard curve $2y^2=x^4-17$ is isomorphic over $\Bbb{Q}$ to one of the two curve, **$y^2=-34x^4+2$ or $y^2=-34x^4-2$.**

But I'm stucking which curve is isomorphic to $2y^2=x^4-17$.
Those tree curves are isomorphic over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.

What is the strategy to determine which curve is isomorphic to $2y^2=x^4-17$ ?

Reference: Silverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'', chapter 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the change of variables $x\mapsto 1/x,y\mapsto y/2x^2$, the equation $2y^2=x^4-17$ becomes
\begin{align*}
2\big(\frac y{2x^2}\big)^2&=x^{-4}-17\\
y^2&=2-34x^4.
\end{align*}
Conversely, it is not isomorphic to $y^2=-34x^4-2$, since it has no $\mathbb R$-points.

Comment: Thank you very much.　I find it challenging to identify the appropriate variable transformations between curves, and I realize it might be difficult to verbalize, but could you please share any tips or strategies for finding the right variable transformations in such cases?

Comment: $x^4-17$ and $2-34x^4=2(1-17x^4)$ visibly look like they are related by $x\mapsto 1/x$.